# How to create an array while using latex \DeclareOption

Tags: arrays, class-options

I have a class in which an option is to state a code and the resulting programme of study is represented at various points throughout a document. The option also changes a number of other blocks of text related to each programme. For example:

```
\DeclareOption{AK3696}{\def\degreetitle{Bachelor of Arts (Honours)}}
```

However, there are 156 codes and while having 156 options declared works, it really grates. I would prefer to have all the codes and programme names in a separate file that can be easily updated (these may change twice each year with old ones deleted and new ones added).

Is there a way, using `\DeclareOption`, to define the programme codes and programme names in an array of structured objects and using the programme code as a pointer?

The array should not include the class code, for example in the form below:

"AK3696","Bachelor of Arts (Honours)"

"AK3656","Bachelor of Applied Science (Honours)"

"AK3670","Bachelor of Art and Design (Honours)"

"AK3712","Bachelor of Business with Honours"

"AK3687","Bachelor of Computer and Information Sciences (Honours)"

Comment: Do you want to pull the data out of a `.csv`?

Comment: Ideally, yes. But for now it is sufficient to have a text file that can be read.

Comment: My apologies. I should add that I would also like to remove the class code text from the file and be reduced to a comma separated list. I have edited the question to include this.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit too generic. I'd exploit the `\DeclareOption*` feature:

```
\DeclareOption*{\edef\alanclass@givencode{\CurrentOption}}
```

After `\ProcessOptions` you can input your code file in the format

```
%% file alanclasscodes.def
\alanclass@code{AK3696}{%
  \def\degreetitle{Bachelor of Arts (Honours)}%
}
%%% and so on for the other codes
```

by doing

```
\def\alanclass@code#1#2{%
  \def\next{#1}%
  \ifx\alanclass@givencode\next
    #2%
  \fi
}
\input{alanclasscodes.def}
```

so the TeX code relative to the chosen options is executed and the others are discarded.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work, no matter how I altered it. Is it because there may be  a restriction on the number of `\DeclareOption*` statements? Clearly there already exists `\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}`

Comment: @Alan There can be only one `\DeclareOption*` statement. I can't read your mind or your class.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. I thought so. As it happens, merely putting in `\input{programmes.def}` into the group of option declarations allows an external file to be read. Half way to the goal :)

Comment: @Alan Yes, if you are happy of having the `.def` file with the format `\DeclareOption{<option>}{<code>}`

Comment: It will do until I can find a longer term solution. Thank you for helping to clarify the issues.